# Accessing swing components created in method

Tags: java, swing

I have a class that builds my gui. One part of the gui is a jtabbed pane, the panels for this are created in a method, they are all the same and have a jtextarea and some jbuttons.

How can I access the components in each tab from other methods/classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put this components into class fields. For example if you need to access button make field

`private Button myButton;`

Create it in method `createUI()` and then use it in method `doSomething()`.

Other way is to store the container only (e.g. panel) and then access its components using `panel.getComponents()`. Use this method only if you really have very similar components and do not have to distinguish among them. For example you want to change color of all components etc.

Comment: Are you saying I should create a separate class for building each tab?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `getTabCount()`, `getTitleAt()`, `indexOfTab()`, and `getComponent()`.  See more info [here](http://edelstein.pebbles.cs.cmu.edu/jadeite/main.php?api=java6&state=class&package=javax.swing&class=JTabbedPane)

Comment: I'm not having trouble accessing the tab as I'm storing them as components in an Arraylist. I'm having trouble accessing the components like the jtextarea on the tab.

Comment: If you know the precise structure of the tabs, you can call `getComponent()` on the appropriate sub-components.  If you do not know the exact structure, you will need to look for a way to identify the components (if the builder method is yours, it could keep a list of the created components) -- a better way would be to create a class that models the tab and create instances of this class to get easy access to the inner components